# Calculate Total Based on Selected Options Part 2

Tags: cognito-forms

I am using the second solution in the below link to try to format a simple calculation but it is not working.  Any advice as for what is going wrong?

I am trying to calculate an amount based on one numeric field "TotalPayrollHours" multiplied by 1 of 2 choices in a currency field.

[image: screen shot]

[How do I calculate grand totals based on selected options in Cognito Forms?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/74887/how-do-i-calculate-grand-totals-based-on-selected-options-in-cognito-forms/74905#74905)

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation field, `TotalPayrollHours`, is a numeric calculation, but the type of the calculation field is set to `Text`.  Just change the type of this calculation field to `Number` and your `DailyLaborTotal` calculation will work correctly.